# Rewriting urls using mod_rewrite : Error with multiple rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following code in .htaccess

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?(/(edit)+)(/([^/]+))?/?$ edit.php?secret=Y7qD7&category=$1&slug=$3&edit=$5&part=$7 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/([^/]+))?/?$ content.php?category=$1&slug=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ content.php [L]
```

What I expect to achieve is

```
http://example.com/test/test1/edit/part   to  edit.php?category=test&slug=test1&edit=edit&part=part
http://example.com/test/edit/part   to  edit.php?category=test&slug=&edit=edit&part=part
```

(above rewrite is working as expected)

```
 `http://example.com/test/test/` to `content.php?category=test&slug=test` 
 `http://example.com/test/` to `content.php?category=test&slug=`
```

(Please note that there is no "/edit/" & "/part/" in above 2 urls)

for above two rewrites, first one is working fine but the second one is not working as expected. The last one get rewrite to content.php?category=content.php&slug= which is not correct.

Also trailing slash should not make a difference for the rewrite.

Could somebody please show me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't check why the rule in your question doesn't work as expected, but you may try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)?/?
RewriteRule .*    edit.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4     [L]
```

Maps silently:

`http://example.com/val1/` up to

`http://example.com/val1/val2/val3/val4/` with or without trailing slashes

To:

`http://example.com/edit.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4`

The maximum quantity of `valN` values passed in the incoming URL, is 4. The minimum is 1. That range can be adjusted modifying the rule, though.

When any `valN` is not present in the incoming URL, the value in the corresponding key-value pair in the query added to the substitution URL, will be empty.

However, the `key` will always be present in the query as all `keys` are fixed strings not passed by the incoming URL.

This rule-set is tested and working and it should be tested without any other rule that might get in conflict with it. I didn't check the other rules in the question and can't say if they work or if they could affect this one. That was not part of the question.

#### UPDATE

**Redirecting to edit.php:**

Mapping to edit.php is required only when there are 3 or 4 folders in the URL-path.

The modified rule-set is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !edit\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*    edit.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4     [L,QSA]
```

Maps silently:

`http://example.com/val1/val2/val3/` up to

`http://example.com/val1/val2/val3/val4/` with or without trailing slashes

To:

`http://example.com/edit.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3&key4=val4`

The maximum quantity of valN values passed in the incoming URL, is 4. The minimum is 3.

---

**Redirecting to content.php:**

Mapping to content.php is very similar to the previous one, except is done only when the number of folders is 1 or 2.

So the rule-set is basically the same with less regex groups:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !content\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*    content.php?key1=%1&key2=%2   [L,QSA]
```

Maps silently:

`http://example.com/val1/`  up to

`http://example.com/val1/val2/` with or without trailing slashes

To:

`http://example.com/content.php?key1=val1&key2=val2`

The maximum quantity of valN values passed in the incoming URL, is 2. The minimum is 1.

The **complete rule-set** is like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !edit\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*    edit.php?key1=%1&key2=%2&key3=%3&key4=%4  [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !content\.php  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)?/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*    content.php?key1=%1&key2=%2   [L,QSA]
```

Hope I understood what you want.

Comment: thanks! this is great. But i want to redirect to two different files. i used first rule to redirect to edit.php, i also tried to use another rule to redirect to content.php

Comment: Please update your question with all your requirements, with **examples**. It is impossible to guess what you need from the rules, specially if they don't work and are the reason for the question.

Comment: i've edited the question. Please have a look when you have time.

Comment: @Ninearts Updated my answer. Hope it is what you need.

Comment: You are my hero! :) Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Exactly what i wanted.